# Need to give guest profile access to documents

Tags: community, files, content, document, guest-user

I need to give the guest user profile access to view files/documents (PDF, Excel, Word, etc.).

I have a **public** Customer Service/Napili community with Knowledge set up. Guest users can see the articles just fine, but there are some articles where we want to display an existing PDF, but it seems like they don't have access to the Document file where it's stored. I have given the guest profile access to the document folder via  public group and I have checked the "Externally Available" box on the document. I also ensured that the guest profile has Read access on the Documents object.

Is there any kind of content that the guest profile can access, whether it's a document, find, content, or something else?

Comment: What the issue you are facing for guest users? is that document is not accessible. I know you can create content and externally sharing link can be created which can be accessed by anyone.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I have uploaded a PDF as a Document in Saleforce. I've marked it as externally available and it's in a folder that the guest profile has access to. The PDF embedded into a Knowledge article via and iFrame. I could add a hyperlink to the Document instead, but I can't figure out what URL to use. I figure I can't use the internal document location because the guest user only has access to the community domain.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is marked as `Externally Available` checkbox, then if the image is sent in email template to the external user then that can be displayed without login into Salesforce. Refer [Display and Edit Document Properties](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=docs_edit.htm&type=5)

Better, upload the pdf as Files and get the link from `Share via link` and use that in knowledge article, so anyone from outside organization can access.

[image: file sharing]

Comment: Do you know if "Externally Available" on Documents mean guest users or community users? I am not emailing the Document. I want to give guest users the ability to click a hyperlink and view the document while in a Community. I will probably just add a custom File field on the Article Type and use that instead, but I'm still curious if there's a way to give guest users access to Documents via hyperlink.